# How to create a responsive grid layout in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

It's common practice to have some data that has multiple properties in an array to be displayed in a device of a viewport, that is either `compact` or `wide` (iPhone, iPad, portrait/landscape, etc). For example, we might want to show a 1 column of 2 items in "portrait compact view", or a 1 column and 4 items in a "portrait wide view".

Code wise, we have the `UserInterfaceSizeClass`, that can be used as follows:

```
@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
@Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?

...

HStack {
    if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
}
```

Or, something like calculating the `ratio`:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
  if proxy.size.width > 324.0/2.0 {
    WideView()
  } else {
    NarrowView()
  }
}
```

And a grid can be understood as a 2D array, that we can iterate over the desired number of columns and nested in the loop, loop through the desired number of rows.

```
VStack {
    ForEach(0 ..< self.rows, id: \.self) { row in
        HStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< self.columns, id: \.self) { column in
              ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this far makes sense and comprehended as some basic principles used independently of the tech stack.

So, given a list of 1-dimensional collection of data (please assume a big number of planets):

```
class Planet {
    var name: String
    var size: Double

    init(name:String, size:Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    }
}

var planets = [Planet]()
let planet = Planet(name: "Mars", size: 30.5)
planets.append(planet)
```

The data needs to be allocated to the response grid view.

So, what's the best approach to create a responsive grid layout in SwiftUI, considering the data and the different viewports and device portrait/landscape modes exposed above?

Let know if there are good practices to approach this!